# Laravel / PHPUnit - Test a forever running command

Tags: laravel, command, phpunit

I have an artisan command that runs forever until canceled explicitly. How can I test that using PHPUnit? Do I need to run it for X amount of time and then kill it and check results? Or is it possible to run the command in the background and check results for x amount of time, and then when the test ends the command gets killed?

Comment: It sounds like testing the exit code is not important since it doesn't exit. You might want to test the functions within this command instead.

Comment: May I ask what is this "infinite" command doing? Why do you need to have an infinite command instead of a Job, or trigger a listener due to an event? Having and using an "infinite" command in Laravel is 100% a red flag something is wrong, or you are not using the framework correctly. Could you share more info, please?